# Angular tag *ngIf hides elements for karma debugelement query, even if boolean value is true

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I want to test a component and I have simplified the HTML now to:

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="getTrue()">
    <h4>Teststuff</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my component  I have method getTrue():

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
    selector: 'testforkarma',
    templateUrl: './testforkarma.component.html',
})

export class TestForKarma implements OnInit {

    constructor(
    ) { }

    public getTrue(): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.info('ngOnInit');
    }

}
```

Then my testcode is:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule, By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { TestForKarma } from './testforkarma.component';


describe('TestForKarmaComponent', () => {

    beforeEach(async () => {

        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
            ],
            imports: [
                CommonModule,
                BrowserModule
            ],
            providers: [
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    });


    it('find something', () => {

        let component: TestForKarma;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestForKarma>;
        let el: DebugElement;
        let queryResult: DebugElement;


        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestForKarma);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        el = fixture.debugElement;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.whenStable().then(
            () => {
                queryResult = el.query(By.css('h4'));
                console.info('done query');
                expect(queryResult).not.toBeNull();
            }
        );

    });
});
```

When I debug the test queryResult is null.
When I remove the *ngIf="getTrue()" from the html, debug the test again, queryResult is filled.

I am getting this message in the console:

NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'div' (used in the 'TestForKarma' component template).
If the 'ngIf' is an Angular control flow directive, please make sure that either the 'NgIf' directive or the 'CommonModule' is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.

But I include CommonModule I think..?

I am totally lost and looking at the code for hours now. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try to change the function call in the template with a TRUE and try to see if the result is the same, then change to false, just for check, for play a bit with the issue.

Comment: place the fixture.detectChanges() after the fixture.whenStable, just some ideas, actually i do not have access to my computer to make some tests

Comment: I tried <div *ngIf="true"> that gives the same result. Also switching detectChanges and whenStable did not help.

Comment: Looks like `CommonModule` not being imported.

Comment: I have added CommonModule to the import list of TestBed.configureTestingModule.

Comment: I will just edit the question and supply the full code, I actually made a small separate component now. Moment ...

Comment: I set up an identical test and it passes. Did you include all your code?

Comment: You're right! Thanks for trying it out! I found some suggestions and tried them, and then updated my code in the question, and then it was out of sync.. My apologies! Thank you so much for double checking. I think I know what I did wrong now: not including the component in the declarations. I will change the code answer my own question!

Comment: hahahaa you have learn a hard to forget lesson :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying some things out, and I am so sorry also updating the code in the question wrongly (now it is right or actually wrong of course) I found out what I did wrong: Not including the component in the declarations!

```
declarations: [
    TestForKarmaComponent
]
```

Here is the full working code again, for people with the same problem:

html:

```
<div>
  <div *ngIf="getTrue()">
    <h4>Teststuff</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

typescript of the component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'testforkarma',
    templateUrl: './testforkarma.component.html',
})

export class TestForKarmaComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
    ) {
        console.info('constructor');
    }

    public getTrue(): boolean {
        return true;
    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        console.info('ngOnInit');
    }

}
```

And the now working karma test:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { TestForKarmaComponent } from './testforkarma.component';


describe('TestForKarmaComponent', () => {

    beforeEach(async () => {

        await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [
                TestForKarmaComponent
            ],
            imports: [
            ],
            providers: [
            ]
        })
            .compileComponents();
    });


    it('test to find something in the html', () => {

        const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestForKarmaComponent);
        const component = fixture.componentInstance;
        const el = fixture.debugElement;
        let queryResult: DebugElement;

        fixture.detectChanges();

        fixture.whenStable().then(
            () => {
                queryResult = el.query(By.css('h4'));
                console.info('done query');
                expect(queryResult).not.toBeNull();
            }
        );

    });
});
```